# How to query like this in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have documents like this:

```
{
'body': '',
'date': '',
'agency_id': ''
}
```

I want to get documents with these conditions:

**body contains :**

```
all of ['word1', 'word2 word3', 'word4']  
Or all of: ['word5 word6', 'word7']  
or  all of: ['word8 word9', 'word10']  
And agency_id in ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
```

Would you please tell me how to create this query?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want you need to use two **must** clauses, one for `body` and other for `agency_id`. In case of `body` you can specify your three conditions and use a minimum should match as 1. Should be something like this:

```
{
  "size" : 10,
  "query" : {
    "function_score" : {
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : {
            "bool" : {
              "should" : [ {
                "query_string" : {
                  "query" : "word1 worrd2 word3 word4",
                  "fields" : [ "body" ],
                  "default_operator" : "and"
                }
              }, {
                "query_string" : {
                  "query" : "word5 worrd6 word7",
                  "fields" : [ "body" ],
                  "default_operator" : "and"
                }
              }, {
                "query_string" : {
                  "query" : "word8 worrd9 word10",
                  "fields" : [ "body" ],
                  "default_operator" : "and"
                }
              } ],
              "minimum_should_match" : "1"
            }
          },
          "must" : {
            "query": {
              "terms" : { "agency_id" : [ "id1", "id2", "id3" ]}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Just make sure you use some analyzer to generate tokens for each word inside `body`. If you don't need any special feature you can just use **standard** analyzer.

Comment: word2 and word3 must be consider as one word and ofcourse word8 word9. what to do for this?

Comment: Can you add some example of content inside the body?